# Use requestAnimationFrame in React Native

Tags: react-native

How to use requestAnimationFrame in react native.

I use this for the performance of TouchableOpacity like this

```js
this.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
    if (this.state.scrollEnabled)
        this._panel.transitionTo({toValue: 0});
    else {
        this.setState({scrollEnabled: true}, () => {
            this._panel.transitionTo({toValue: height})
        })
    }
});
```

And return this error

> this.requestAnimationFrame is not a function

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to remove `this` from the first line:

```js
requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      ....
});
```

Comment: Thank you I had an interesting mistake :)

Answer (score 1):

**Update Nov 19:** The [previous documentation](https://web.archive.org/web/20190309012525/https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers) mentioned the `TimerMixin` I am referring to in my answer, but it's now been removed from the documentation. So using the native browser API should be the recommended approach (which is already the accepted answer).

<s>Actually it is recommended not to use timing functions such as `requestAnimationFrame` directly in react-native. It's recommended to use `TimerMixin` instead, and doing that you end up calling it like the code in the original question.</s>

So maybe a better answer would be "you're missing the TimerMixin".

Here's the official documentation explaining this bit: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers#timermixin

Comment: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance - there's nothing on using TimerMixin as the better solution in the performance article. Care to elaborate on why TimerMixin is better?

Comment: @powerup7 Seems like they've updated the docs and it's no longer there, you can see here what they were saying about it before: https://web.archive.org/web/20190309012525/https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/timers

I'll update my response to reflect this new information.

Comment: Cheers. Thanks for actually replying.